# My website showing on two domains

Tags: php, html, dns

My website is showing on two domain as, I am developing it on my own domain, how can it be possible, there is one another domain that I don't know whose? but when I open that link then there also it is showing same. Is that Hacked, Or any one getting access to the website?

I don't know how to prevent other domain to link to my website.

If that is the case then, please suggest some, how to prevent my website to be seen on two domains?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have put **php** tag so I would suggest something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'rtc') {
    exit;
}
```

However its better to handle this kind of things in your http server settings. For example Apache has [virtual named hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Answer (score 0):

another is pointed to your domain name please check that domain name pointed with which nameserver or ip address

by testing with http://who.is/